# Detouring and using a _thiscall as a hook (GCC calling convention)

Tags: c++, gcc, this, detours, mprotect

I've recently been working on detouring functions (only in Linux) and so far I've had great success. I was developing my own detouring class until I found [this](http://www.criticalsecurity.net/index.php/topic/32106-function-hooking-via-detourtrampoline/). I modernized the code a bit and converted it to C++ (as a class of course). That code is just like any other detour implementation, it replaces the original function address with a JMP to my own specified 'hook' function. It also creates a 'trampoline' for the original function.

Everything works flawlessly but I'd like to do one simple adjustement. I program in pure C++, I use no global functions and everything is enclosed in classes (just like Java/C#). The problem is that this detouring method breaks my pattern. The 'hook' function *needs* to be a static/non-class function.

What I want to do is to implement support for _thiscall hooks (which should be pretty simple with the GCC [_thiscall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#thiscall) convention). I've had no success modifying this code to work with _thiscall hooks. What I want as an end result is something just as simple as this; `PatchAddress(void * target, void * hook, void * class);`. I'm not asking anyone to do this for me, but I would like to know how to solve/approach my problem?

From what I know, I should only need to increase the 'patch' size (i.e it's now 5 bytes, and  I should require an additional 5 bytes?), and then before I use the JMP call (to my hook function), I push my 'this' pointer to the stack (which should be as if I called it as a member function). To illustrate:

```
push 'my class pointer'
jmp <my hook function>
```

Instead of just having the 'jmp' call directly/only. Is that the correct approach or is there something else beneath that needs to be taken into account (note: I do not care about support for VC++ _thiscall)?

NOTE: here's is my implementation of the above mentioned code: [header](http://pastebin.com/pRMpxex5) : [source](http://pastebin.com/zqP8Qm8d), uses [libudis86](http://udis86.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: What you call “pure C++” is debatable. Enclosing everything in classes makes no sense in C++. Pure C++ uses modules properly.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I am reminded of the old slogan "C++ for writing better C", but replace C for Java. :)  But I do approve of the question (pl1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried several different methods and among these were JIT compile (using [libjit](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/dotgnu-pnet/libjit-releases/)) which proved successful but the method did not provide enough performance for it to be usable. Instead I turned to [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi/), which is used for calling functions dynamically at run-time. The [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi/) library had a closure API (`ffi_prep_closure_loc`) which enabled me to supply my 'this' pointer to each closure generated. So I used a static callback function and converted the `void` pointer to my object type and from there I could call any non-static function I wished!

Comment: Superb, I just tried to automate the generation of 70 hooks (I hooked Callback Registration function) using lambda closures, but was told that it wouldn't work.  My next step was libjit too, but I will see if your solution can help me.

We're not using classes for our hooks, but we do use a namespace to keep it semi-organised, the idea of having you hooks as classes is absolute insane (is what I would have said if you hadn't made it work).